# what kind of code i can add so i can avoid captcha which occur sometimes or fill that particular captcha

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my actual script which works fine till captcha shows up.

```
driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/battle_trainer.php")
# identify Enter Trainer Name/Number
driver.find_element_by_name("Trainer").send_keys(Trainer_Battle_ID)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
for x in range(100):
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
```

This kind of captcha sometimes occur in this website

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfLyF.jpg

i also manage to get source code page of this captcha

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmS0u.jpg

i tried my self to add some kind of script so whenever captcha occurs then it will fill out it and resume the work but it failed

i posted below the code i tried to create

```
driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/battle_trainer.php")
# identify Enter Trainer Name/Number
driver.find_element_by_name("Trainer").send_keys(Trainer_Battle_ID)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
time.sleep(1.0)
if("CAPTCHA"):
    # Execute a script in the browser
    webbrowser.execute_script("""

    // Set the value of the input to the value of the CAPTCHA text
    document.querySelector("#txtInput").value = document.querySelector("#txtCaptcha").value

    """)
    time.sleep(1.5)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
else :
for x in range(100):
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
    time.sleep(1.5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Continue >>']").click()
```

but this second code failed. is there a way to avoid captchas or fill it out.
i have posted captcha example above, normally such kind of captchas shows up sometimes after
this phase

```
driver.get("https://www.tppcrpg.net/battle_trainer.php")
# identify Enter Trainer Name/Number
driver.find_element_by_name("Trainer").send_keys(Trainer_Battle_ID)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("submit").click()
time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: No, you can't avoid it.  The whole POINT of a "captcha" image is to prevent the kind of cheating you are doing.  There are services you can use where you send them the image, they dispatch it to a human who solves the captcha and returns the code to you.  You could try that, but I find the whole concept highly unethical.

Answer (score 0):

Very small world. I actually have done the same thing as you on the same exact website a couple of years ago. I never figured out a nice way to handle it but an idea that I had was using image recognition to extract the characters and then fill the field. I never got around to it so I had to manually fill the captcha myself. Good luck sir.